# SSRS Single row for Grouping

Tags: reporting-services

I'm working with SharePoint Lists, I have 2 Lists for this issue i.e. Movies & Theatres. Only one list is used tough, because Theatres reference a movie.

(I know this is weird but I'm not actually working with movies and theatres, it's just using an analogy so anyone could understand the problem so let's assume each Theatre only plays a single movie :-P )

So from the Theatres list I create a dataset with following fields: Linked_Movie (Title), Country, Theatre_Number.

I want to create a report that shows a tablix that lists all Movie-titles with all the countries it's shown in and a count of the theatres that are playing that movie. So the tablix should look like example below:

```
MovieTitle | Country   | # of theatres
           |           |
Movie 1    | Country A | 5
           | Country B | 10
SubTotal   |         2 | 15
           |           | 
Movie 2    | Country C | 15
SubTotal   |         1 | 15
           |           |
Total      |         3 | 30
```

I have already created a tablix which groups on Linked_Movie first and Country second. Then in the details-section I just count the theatres that play that certain movie in that specific country. To achieve this I created a second dataset with the exact same data so I could use *LookUpSet.Length*. But even though my calculations are correct the tablix still generates a row for each individual theatre. So my tablix actually looks like example below:

```
MovieTitle | Country   | # of theatres
           |           |
Movie 1    | Country A | 5
           |           | 5
           |           | 5
           |           | 5
           |           | 5
 ....      | ...       | ...
```

So if anyone knows how I would be able to achieve a tablix like the first example that would be greatly appreciated.

If anything is still unclear please don't hesitate to ask.

Kind regards
Gravinco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by adding a calculated field to the dataset named MovieCountry.

After this I put the expression below as the condition for 'Row visibility' and the visiblity of the '=(Details)' properties:

```
=iif(Fields!MovieCountry.Value = Previous(Fields!MovieCountry.Value), True, False)
```

This way I only get a single row for each movie and country combination.

Any questions are always welcome!